# how can I make the server receive pictures from several clients sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, client

so here is my server code that receive a picture from my client

```
public void Hey()
{
    Functions.ServerSend("Picture");
    if (Functions.serverrecievetext().CompareTo("Okay") == 0)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        LingerOption lo = new LingerOption(false, 0);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, lo);

        try
        {
            sck.Bind(Login.ip_ep);
            sck.Listen(100);
            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
            byte[] buff = new byte[300000];

            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

            read = accepted.Receive(buff, buff.Length, 0);
            m.Write(buff, 0, read);
            while (read > 0)
            {
                read = accepted.Receive(buff, buff.Length,0);
                if (read != 0)
                    m.Write(buff, 0, read);
            }

            Bitmap p = new Bitmap(m, false);
            m.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = p;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            accepted.Close();

            sck.Dispose();
            sck.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

        }
    }
}



private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Hey);
    t.Start();
}
```

it works just fine for one client and here is the client code :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p = Functions.ClientRecieve();
    if (p.CompareTo("Picture") == 0)
    {
        Functions.ClientSendText("Okay");
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b as Image);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = b;
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            sck.Connect(Login.ip_ep);

            MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            sck.Send(s.ToArray());
            sck.Disconnect(true);
            sck.Dispose();
            sck.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Functions.ClientSendText("Okay");
        timer1.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I want the server to have the ability to receive different pictures from different clients at the same time (if that's even possible)
note I open a new server when I click on button and it gives command to start new client too
so when I click on the button two times I want to have two server forms each one is getting different pictures 
thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

You want to receive different pictures from multiple clients at a same time. Then you'll need to learn using threads. The recipient server will listen for clients and start a new thread for each client where code to receive image will be written. Like this you can simultaneously receive or send data in parallel manner.

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm) will get you started with threads in c#

Comment: I know threading basics how can I also did a thread for each client on the button click which starts the server the problem is when I start a new server the server start receiving from both clients not just one

Comment: I can't understand what you want or problem is? But your server code certainly needs to be multithreaded in order to handle multiple clients and since connection is TCP and your code currently doesn't implement that. It won't be problem receiving from two or more clients simultaneously, just each thread will handle each connection independently.
You say, you want to have multiple server receiving, that's not possible with same port. We cannot run multiple server in same port.